# style conflict between javascript and css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have built a little element 3d rotator for infinite rotating in either direction on the X or Y axis. However I am running into what I think is a css style conflict. #face2 has a css property that rotates it -180deg . however its not being implemented by the browser.

is this a css conflict perhaps?

you can see the code and the effect in this code pen :

```js
//declaring global variables

window.RotXFrontVal = 0; // by how much to rotate the X value of the front face
window.RotXBackVal = -180; // by how much to rotate the X value of the back face
window.RotYFrontVal = 0; // by how much to rotate the Y value of the front face
window.RotYBackVal = 180; // by how much to rotate the Y value of the back face

$(document).ready(function() {
  //$('#face2').css({'transform': 'rotateX(-180deg)'}, 0);
  //$('#face2').animate({'transform', 'rotateX(-180deg)'}, 0);
   //$('#face2').animate({'transform': 'rotateX(-180deg)'}, 0);
  
  var MyDivSlider = function() { // Here will come the Div Slider by Scroll 

    var scl = $.now(); // Take a time stamp to prevent function from triggering too often

    $(document).on('DOMMouseScroll mousewheel', function MyScroll(event) {
    
      if (($.now() - scl) > 500) {

        if (event.originalEvent.detail > 0 || event.originalEvent.wheelDelta < 0) {
          //Scroll Down
          window.RotXFrontVal = window.RotXFrontVal - 180;
          window.RotXBackVal = window.RotXBackVal - 180;
          console.log("Down.  Front: " + RotXFrontVal + "and" + RotXBackVal + " is Back");
        }

        //Up Scroll 
        else {
          
          window.RotXFrontVal = window.RotXFrontVal + 180;
          window.RotXBackVal = window.RotXBackVal + 180;
          console.log("Up.  Front: " + RotXFrontVal + "and" + RotXBackVal + " is Back");

        }
        $('#face2').css('transform', 'rotateX(' + RotXBackVal + 'deg)');
        $('#face1').css('transform', 'rotateX(' + RotXFrontVal + 'deg)');

        console.log('rotateX(' + RotXFrontVal + ')')
        console.log('rotateX(' + RotXBackVal + ')')

        scl = $.now();

      }
    });
  }();
});
```

```css
body { height:100%; overflow:hidden;}

#card {
      height:300px;
   width: 300px;
   display: block;
   position: relative;
   transform-style: preserve-3d;
   transition: all 1.5s linear;
   perspective: 1000px;
}

#face1 {
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   background: red;
   backface-visibility: hidden;
   transition: transform 1.5s;
   z-index: 2;
}

#face2 {
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   background: blue;
   backface-visibility: hidden;
   transition: transform 1.5s;
   z-index: 1;
   transform: rotateX ( -180deg );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
 <div id="card">
   <div id = "face1">Use the mouse scroll button to rotate me</div>
   <div id = "face2">Use the mouse scroll button to rotate me</div>
 </div>    
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of the whitespace inbetween `rotateX` and `(`

try: `transform: rotateX( -180deg );`

Comment: Thank you! as you said i removed the space and now it works!